# Non type-variable argument in the constraint for Arbitrary typeclass

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism

For an exercise in Chapter 15 of *Haskell Programming From First Principles*, I'm trying to write an `Arbitrary` instance based on another `Arbitrary` instance:

```
module AccumulateRight where

import Data.Semigroup
import Test.QuickCheck

data Validation a b = Fail a | Pass b deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype AccumulateRight a b =
    AccumulateRight (Validation a b) deriving (Eq, Show)

type TestType = AccumulateRight String [Int]

instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (AccumulateRight a b) where
    _ <> (AccumulateRight (Fail x)) = Fail x
    (AccumulateRight (Fail x)) <> _ = Fail x
    (AccumulateRight (Success a)) <> (AccumulateRight (Success b)) =
        AccumulateRight . Success $ a <> b

instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (Validation a b) where
    arbitrary = oneof [Fail <$> arbitrary, Pass <$> arbitrary]

instance Arbitrary (Validation a b) => Arbitrary (AccumulateRight a b) where
    arbitrary = AccumulateRight <$> arbitrary

semigroupAssoc :: (Eq m, Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
semigroupAssoc a b c = (a <> (b <> c)) == ((a <> b) <> c)

type Assoc = TestType -> TestType -> TestType -> Bool

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: Assoc)
```

but the following error occurs:

```
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Arbitrary (Validation a b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • In the context: Arbitrary (Validation a b)
      While checking an instance declaration
      In the instance declaration for ‘Arbitrary (AccumulateRight a b)’
   |
22 | instance Arbitrary (Validation a b) => Arbitrary (AccumulateRight a b) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

So am I doing anything wrong here? Why can't I use the typeclass of an existing data as the constraint here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a silly restriction that was put in place before it was understood how difficult typeclasses would be to implement. Turns out it's easy enough to support, so there's a language extension -- mentioned in the error -- that lets you say that. You can turn it on by adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

to the top of your file, and as extensions go this one is considered completely benign. However, in this case, you should not turn it on, and instead should just write

```
instance (Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (AccumulateRight a b)
```

-- after all, `(Arbitrary a, Arbitrary b)` are exactly the conditions under which `Arbitrary (Validation a b)` holds.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on what FlexibleContexts mean and how it relates to the error here?

Comment: @yhylord There's not much to say. The Report says that in contexts (including `instance` contexts), classes may only be applied to (type) variables. Since `Validation a b` is not a variable, `Arbitrary (Validation a b)` is not allowed in instance contexts -- but since `a` is a variable and `b` is a variable, `Arbitrary a` and `Arbitrary b` are both fine. The `FlexibleContexts` extension does nothing more than lift this restriction.